# Dynamic Tab visibility

Tags: apex

Is it possible to hide a custom objects' tab dynamically for a user?

Also does hiding a tab means visibility to custom object is gone?If not do we need to update the sharing rules as well
My deciding field is a formula field,and for that reason i cannot specify that in sharing rules .can sharing rule be modified by customisation?

Answer (score 3):

You can control the tab visibility for a user dynamically.

1) Create a permission set in which you set a particular tab visible.

2) Now in insert a record in the permissionSetAssignment object.

```
 permissionSetAssignment p = new permissionsetassignment();
 p.assigneeId = userId; //Id of the user for which you need to make the tab visisble.
 p.permissionsetId = permissionSetId; // the Id of the permission that you just created.
 insert p;
```

Also you have make sure that the user's profile doesn't have tab visible otherwise this solution will not work.